# Convert multi-arrow function into an-line call

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to convert the following to an in-line expression?

```js
const
    rePlace = (count) => (m) => {
        count ++;
        return (parseInt(m) > 255 || count > 4) ? '<invalid>' : m;
    },
    regex = /\d+(?=(\.|$))/g,
    potential_ips = ['1.2.3.4.5', '12.34.45.56', '123.456.789.0', '1.2.3.4.5.6'];  
for (let ip of potential_ips) {
    ip = ip.replace(regex, rePlace(0));
    console.log(ip);
}
```

My first attempt was to call the function with `(0)` as a parameter, but I think on successive calls it fails:

```js
regex = /\d+(?=(\.|$))/g;
potential_ips = ['1.2.3.4.5', '12.34.45.56', '123.456.789.0', '1.2.3.4.5.6'] ;  
for (let ip of potential_ips) {
    ip = ip.replace(regex, ((count) => (m) => count++, (parseInt(m) > 255 || count > 4) ? '<invalid>' : m)(0));
    console.log(ip);
}
```

Is there a way to do this, or not possible?

Comment: @Pointy could you please clarify that (perhaps even adding an answer for it)? As I'm new to javascript so really just learning the basics and such.

Comment: Yea sorry I was interrupted by a phone call. It returns a function that expects to be used as the callback to `.replace()`. That will be called for each string of digits matched.

Comment: By building the callback that way, it can use a private `count` variable (the parameter to the outer function). That makes `count++` make sense; each function returned from `rePlace()` has its own `count`, in other words.

Comment: @Pointy I see, so in other words the above approach could not be done in-line, correct?

Comment: Well I think it probably could; I'll post an answer. I'm  not sure it's *better* but it's different. *edit* oh wait; no, that wouldn't really work. The original code looks a little odd, but it's probably the cleanest way to do it. If you wrote the original with traditional `function` functions it might be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const potential_ips = [
  '1.2.3.4.5', 
  '12.34.45.56',
  '123.456.789.0',
  '1.2.3.4.5.6',
  '::0',
  'www.google.com'
];  
for (const ip of potential_ips) {
    console.log(
    ip.split('.')
      .map((m,i) => (parseInt(m) <= 255 && parseInt(m) >= 0 && i < 4) ? m : '<invalid>')
      .join('.')
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the original, but with traditional `function` functions:

```js
const
    rePlace = function(count) {
        return function(segment) {
          count ++;
          return (parseInt(segment) > 255 || count > 4) ? '<invalid>' : segment;
        };
    },
    regex = /\d+(?=(\.|$))/g,
    potential_ips = ['1.2.3.4.5', '12.34.45.56', '123.456.789.0', '1.2.3.4.5.6']; 
    
for (let ip of potential_ips) {
    ip = ip.replace(regex, rePlace(0));
    console.log(ip);
}
```

It might be a little clearer expressed that way.